# Add UINavigationBar Shadow Application Wide?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

There are a few tutorial about showing how to add a shadow to a UINavigation bar, but is there any method which would best suit adding this shadow application wide, rather than in a single instance?

Or is my only option to simply have a sub-classed nab bar in every single view of my application? Thought there might be a quicker, easier way than doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a category of `UINavigationBar` called `UINavigationBar+dropshadow.m` and put this in the file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface UINavigationBar (dropshadow)

-(void) applyDefaultStyle;

@end

@implementation UINavigationBar (dropshadow)

-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow{
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];
    [self applyDefaultStyle];
}

- (void)applyDefaultStyle { 
    // add the drop shadow
    self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 3.0);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: self.clipsToBounds = NO; required but worked really well, thanks!

Comment: How would you solve the (auto-)rotation problem with a category?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with iOS6, you can use the Appearance proxy to do that.

Here's the Apple Class Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

**EDIT 1** Fixed required iOS version (was mistakenly iOS5 previously)

**EDIT 2**
See this SO question: [Appearance proxy - setShadowImage alternative for iOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690753/appearance-proxy-setshadowimage-alternative-for-ios-5) for a code snippet

Comment: a code sample would be awesome... I couldn't find a way to add shadows to a navigation bar using the UIAppearance proxy...

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited another SO question providing a code snippet into my post.
Also, I just realized that I got it switched up, you need iOS6 for the proxy to work with shadows, not iOS5.
Fixed now, thanks for the feedback.