# Appearance proxy - setShadowImage alternative for iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

Hello I'm using this code to set the shadow image of my navbar:

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)]) {

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-shadow"]];

    [[UIToolbar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tool-bar-shadow"]  forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny];
}
```

However it seems this is iOS 6 only (though I can't say for sure - I can't find documentation about this anywhere). It doesn't work on iOS 5.

Is there some kind of alternative - globally setting an image under the navbar?
I thought of custom UIView, but how to do this globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Add a subview containing the shadow image to your `viewController.view`
2. Add a subview containing the shadow image to your `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`, which will add the image globally on your window. However, it can get a little bit ugly e.g. when displaying a modal view controller.
3. You can subclass `UINavigationBar`, do some magic with subviews in there and then initialize your navigationController via `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[YourNavBarSubclass class] toolbarClass:[UIToolbar class]]`

Answer (score 0):

shadowImage is ios6 only:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImage *shadowImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```